# Why we need an explicit conversion incase od Extension method and not for static methods?

Tags: c#-3.0, extension-methods

Why Extension methods do not use implicit conversions but static methods do? Can anybody explain with a proper example?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the C# spec states:

> An extension method Ci.Mj is eligible if:
>
> ·         Ci is a non-generic, non-nested class
>
> ·         The name of Mj is identifier
>
> ·          Mj is accessible and applicable when applied to the
>   arguments as a static method as shown above
>
> ·         An implicit identity, reference or boxing conversion exists
>   from expr to the type of the first parameter of Mj.

As far as the C# spec is concerned, a user-defined conversion operator is different than an implicit reference conversion, and certainly different than an identity or boxing conversion.

For a hint on why:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void DoSomething(this Bar b)
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Some bar");
    }

    public static void DoSomething(this Boo b)
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Some boo");
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public static implicit operator Bar(Foo f)
    {
        return new Bar();
    }
    public static implicit operator Boo(Foo f)
    {
        return new Boo();
    }
}

public class Bar { }
public class Boo { }

public class Application
{
    private Foo f;
    public void DoWork()
    {
        // What would you expect to happen here?
        f.DoSomething();

        // Incidentally, this doesn't compile either:
        Extensions.DoSomething(f);
    }
}
```

C# could not unambiguously choose which implicit conversion to execute.